# Why replace the @ with %40 in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I register, the email @ replaces with %40. How to set it to a collation for @?
And sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: can you post the code what you have tried

Comment: It's in Flash but I want to set collation or replace the %40 to @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a url encode function from php. and it automatically decodes to the user readable form while printing it to the console or the form onto which you need it.

see this : if `$email` has the encoded thing,

```
$email = urldecode("[email]")
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your register is sending a HTTP GET request, in which case you probably need to use urldecode when you receive the data in PHP

eg:-

```
$email = urldecode($_GET["email"]);
```

Alternatively if you make the request with POST instead of GET then you won't need to do this